# Conditional JSON schema validation based on value of referenced object

Tags: json, jsonschema

Imagine I have a JSON object like the following:

```json
    {
        "sources": [
            {
                "id": "foo",
                "type": "a"
            },
            {
                "id": "bar",
                "type": "b"
            }
        ],
        "data": [
            {
                "source-id": "foo",
                "a-attribute": 10
            },
            {
                "source-id": "bar",
                "b-attribute": 20
            }
        ]
    }
```

Here, the `source-id` in the `data` objects must be equal to one of the `id`s in the `source` objects.

1. How can I express this relationship in JSON Schema?
2. How can I do [conditional subschema application](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html) for the `data` objects based on the value of the `type` property of the referred `sources` object?

Expanding a bit on 2., I would like for example that when the `type` of the referred `source` is `a`, then I have to specify `a-attribute` and cannot specify `b-attribute`.

And when the `type` of the referred source is `b`, then I should be forced to specify `b-attribute` and not `a-attribute`.

Can this be achieved with JSON Schema, or do I need to write custom validation code?

Answer (score 1):

I was told in the JSON Schema Slack that JSON Schema today cannot express relational integrity constraints.

So what I would like to do is not achievable with a schema but requires separate validation.